# 'overflow: scroll' not working in Safari (11.0.2) on MacBook (10.13.2 ) or any browser on iPhoneX (11.2.1)

Tags: css, django, iframe, scroll, overflow

On the webpage linked below if you select a barber it reveals a hidden 'div' (id="booking-right") containing an 'iframe' (class="iframe") with a booking page. We have set our CSS to allow the 'iframe' to scroll up and down within the hidden 'div' using 'overflow: scroll'. As you may be able to see, this works fine in Chrome on MacBook, but won't work in Safari on MacBook or on any browser on my iPhoneX. This is a real problem because it means clients won't be able to scroll down to select appointment times for our barbers.

http://cuttersclub.webfactional.com/barbers/

Any help would be much appreciated!

My code:

Full code can be seen at: https://github.com/cuttersclub/cutters_club/tree/master/src

Or check out the relevant snippet below:

barbers.html

```
<div id="div">

        <!-- acuity -->

        <div id="booking-div">

            <div id="booking-left"></div>

            <div id="booking-right">
                <a><img id="close-image" src="{% static "img/close-button.svg" %}" alt="My image"></a>
                {% for BarberProfile in queryset_list %}
                    <iframe class="iframe" id="{{BarberProfile.id}}-iframe" src="" frameBorder="0"></iframe><script src="https://d3gxy7nm8y4yjr.cloudfront.net/js/embed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- acuity -->

        <!-- profile -->

        {% for BarberProfile in queryset_list %}

        <a class="profile-div" id="{{BarberProfile.id}}" target="{{BarberProfile.booking_link}}" onClick="toggle_content(this.id)">

            <div id="image" style="background-image: url({{BarberProfile.image.url}})">
                <div id="image-structure"></div>
            </div>

            <h4 id="name"> {{BarberProfile.first_name}} </h4>
            <p id="bio"> {{BarberProfile.bio}} </p>
            <img id="experience-image" src="{% static "img/experience.svg" %}" alt=""><p id="experience">{{BarberProfile.years_of_experience}} experience</p>
            <img id="ideal-image" src="{% static "img/speciality.svg" %}" alt=""><p id="ideal">Ideal for {{BarberProfile.ideal_for}} </p>

        </a>

        {% endfor %}

        <!-- profile -->

</div>
```

barbers.css

```
/*acuity*/

#booking-div{
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
}
    #booking-left{
        position: fixed;
        background-color: black;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    #booking-right{
        position: fixed;
        background-color: white;
        height: 100%;
        right: 0px;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
        #close-image{
            position: absolute;
            right: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            height: 18.75px;
            z-index: 1;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 18.75;
        }
        .iframe{
            position: absolute;
            width: -webkit-calc(100% - 37.5px);
            padding: 41.25 18.75 33.25 18.75; /*bottom margin not responding*/
        }

/*acuity*/

#div{
    display: grid;
    min-height: -webkit-calc(100% - 168.75px);
    padding: 168.75 9.375 0 9.375;
}

    /*profile*/

    .profile-div{
        margin: 0 9.375 18.75 9.375;
    }

        #image{
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 12.5px 0px #EFEFEF;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }
            #image-structure{
                height: 0px;
                padding-top: 100%;
            }
        #name{
            line-height: 13.125px;
            margin: 18.75 0 0 0;
            font-size: 17.5px;
            text-transform: lowercase;
        }
            #name:first-letter, #experience:first-letter, #ideal:first-letter{
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }
        #bio{
            line-height: 23.75px;
            margin: 12.5 0 12.5 0;
            color: #3F3F3F;
        }
        #experience{
            line-height: 23.75px;
            margin: 0 0 9.375 33.125;
            text-transform: lowercase;
        }
        #ideal{
            line-height: 23.75px;
            margin: 0 0 18.75 33.125;
            text-transform: lowercase;
        }
        #experience-image, #ideal-image{
            height: 23.75px;
            float: left;
        }

    /*profile*/

@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 600px){
    #div{
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    }
    #booking-left{
        width: 12.5%;
    }
    #booking-right{
        width: 87.5%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 900px){
    #div{
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }
    #booking-left{
        width: -webkit-calc(100% - 500px);
    }
    #booking-right{
        width: 500px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px){
    #div{
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }
    #booking-left{
        width: -webkit-calc(100% - 500px);
    }
    #booking-right{
        width: 500px;
    }
}
```